# UIImageView - Stretch to fit issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app which requires dynamic background images (they are set server side) - the views used are both `UIViewControllers` and `UITableViewControllers`, so I have created classes which extend both controller type and add a background image to each view on load.

All works fine apart from the background image is refusing to stretch on an iPad on the `UIViewController` only - I am using `Xcassets` and have the standard and @2x retina images applied - all works fine on iPhone - and on both for `UITableViewControllers` but the `UIViewController` class doesn't appear to stretch the background on an iPad - it simply displays the image in the top left corner at the standard 320 width size.

This is my code - can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:    [self.prefs stringForKey:@"BGImageBlur"]]];
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    [self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `UIImageView` and providing it the image to set within the view. This will create the `UIImageView` with the frame of the given Image. You must first specify the frame, then set the image. Try this:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.prefs stringForKey:@"BGImageBlur"]]
```

This will create an ImageView that is the same size as its parent. If this is not what you want you'll probably have to specify some other layout constraints.